# SensioLabs Insight cant find SncRedisBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I am running SensioLabs Insights on a project, but it keeps giving me a warning that `A Symfony application should be bootable`. I couldn't agree more and on my local environment, test, stage and production everything works fine.

```
Fatal error detected on file "app/AppKernel.php" at line 22 with message: 

"Uncaught Error: Class 'Snc\RedisBundle\SncRedisBundle' not found in /home/foobar/code/app/AppKernel.php:22
Stack trace:
#0 /home/foobar/code/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(430): AppKernel->registerBundles()
#1 /home/foobar/code/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(130): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
#2 /home/foobar/code/app/InsightAppKernel.php(15) : eval()'d code(7): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
#3 /home/foobar/code/app/InsightAppKernel.php(15): eval()
#4 {main}
  thrown"
```

I tried with the same requirements described here https://insight.sensiolabs.com/what-we-analyse/symfony.application_not_bootable but with no luck. For some reason it just wont detect the bundle.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you execute `composer install` command? It looks like you're missing this package or at least autoloader.

Comment: Insights operate with a `pre_composer_script` and `post_composer_script` operator so I expect that `composer isntall` is part of their runetime analyze. https://insight.sensiolabs.com/help/insight-yml-configuration.html